# Least privilege for a service principal to create another service principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I tried to find some information which application permission is necessary for a service principal to create another AAD applications / service principal but didn't find a least privilege setup.

Currently I assign the SP some directory roles like Directory Writers which probably is to much?

Does anybody know which **application** permission the SP needs to create another SP? Or does the SP needs directory roles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your app creates applications and then creates principals for *them*, then the **Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy** application permission on the Azure AD Graph can do that.

[image: The permission in Azure Portal]

It does not allow the app to create service principals for *other applications* though. That requires quite big app permissions as you noticed.